# How to time web request in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I would like to time how long it takes for CherryPy to return a page when given a request. How may I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a decorator:

```
import datetime
import cherrypy

def request_timer(f, *args, **kwargs):
    def _request_time(f, *args, **kwargs):
        begin = datetime.datetime.now()
        response = f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print cherrypy.log('time took for request %s' % (end - begin))
        return response
    return _request_time(f, *args, **kwargs)

class Root(object):

    @request_timer
    def index(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
    index.exposed = True
```

The log message will go to either screen or your error_log file, depending on your setting.

Comment: The way I understand this code, it times how long the exposed method is executed. I would like to start the timing from where the CherryPy server receives the request until it sends the response. I'm currently looking at the `communicate()` method of the `HTTPConnection` class under the wsgiserver of the source of CherryPy.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what exactly you want to measure. If you want to time just the page handler logic, use the code Y. H. Wong posted. If you want to measure the total time as the client sees it, use something like [Apache `ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html):

```
$ python myproject.py &
$ ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

Comment: This is also one of the methods I plan to use. I am actually trying to see how long the request takes in each part of the stack (network, CherryPy, Cheetah, db, etc.)